# Measuring variables for each turtle using BehaviorSearch

Tags: netlogo, behaviorsearch

I am trying to use BehaviorSearch to get the changes in colour and size of every turtle in my model. So, I would like to obtain a table or csv output which includes the id, colour and size of turtles in my model for every step of my runs. Which I would work with in R afterwards.

I've tried writing below "Measure runs using these reporters" in BehaviorSearch the following specifications:

```
[who] of turtles
[colour] of turtles
[size] of turtles
```

However, the resulting output has a column for runs, a column for steps, and three more columns consisting of lists of all turtles' id, color and size. While I would like to have a single row for run, step and turtle containing its' id, color and size.

What do I need to write different to achieve my desired output?

Answer (score 1):

So you want the who, colour and size to be grouped right? In that case I suggest grouping them into a single list.

```
[(list who colour size)] of turtles
```

Comment: Thank, you! That is not what I was looking for, but is definitively useful, as it is way easier to use the data like that. Do you think there might be a way to obtain a row for each of the grouped lists of 3 elements instead of obtaining a row with a big list containing all of them?

Comment: Oh you want a row per turtle? I don't think that is easy to do here, unless it is always the exact same number of turtles. I suggest doing that in your choice of dataprocessing software afterwards. Even something like excel can split a column into multiple columns quite easily as long as you have a clear divider between each item